# Unable to load a pdf file which has special characters(!@#) in file path. Webview Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, webview

I am working on loading a pdf file in Xamarin through Web view. When the file path has special characters in it, pdf file is not loading.

Below is the code.

if (e.NewElement is PDFView pdfWebView)
            {

```
            this.Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            this.Control.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
            this.Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=file://{pdfWebView.Uri}");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying what you are using, but from the file path, I can safely assume that you are using [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). If that's the case, then you'll need to URL encode the filename. 
According to the [FAQ page](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#can-i-specify-a-different-pdf-in-the-default-viewer):

> You can modify the defaultUrl app option in the web/app_options.js file or you can append the ?file= query string to the viewer URL, e.g. http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf. In the latter case, the PDF path/URL must be encoded using encodeURIComponent()

So, you will simply need to call `encodeURIComponent()` on your path.

Edit: You must encode the URI with the js function `encodeURIComponent()`, because there are some differences how the js function encodes the path, and how C# encodes it.

E.g. Comparing [WebUtility.UrlEcode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=netcore-3.1) docs with [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) docs, we can see that most of the escapes are similar. What is being escaped is:

> encodeURIComponent() escapes all characters except: A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

So far so good. Unfortunately, both methods escape differently the " " (space) symbol.

C#'s method `UrlEncode` does this:

> Each ' ' (space) character is converted to a + (plus) character.

JS' function `encodeURIComponent` does this:

> console.log(encodeURI("ABC abc 123")); // ABC%20abc%20123 (the space gets encoded as %20)

Comment: Thanks Mihail. Encoding is not working. Can you share any example with source code.

Comment: Did you call the JS function `encodeURIComponent()`, or did you encode it yourself, in C#?

Comment: I tried with below approach.
var EncodingStr = WebUtility.UrlEncode($"file://{pdfWebView.Uri}");
Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?{EncodingStr}");

Comment: Like I said, you must use JS' function for encoding - `encodeURIComponent`. Unfortunately, C#'s `UrlEncode` won't work here. You can always, encode it in C#, and then adjust it to what JS will expect. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = "/path/to/local/file"
Java.IO.File myFile = new Java.IO.File(path);
Java.Net.URL url = myFile.ToURI().ToURL();
string urlStr = string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", url, WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri));
urlStr = urlStr.Replace("&", "%26");
Control.LoadUrl(urlStr);
```